# Setting snowflake session variable with powerbi

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, session-variables

I have parameterized views created in snowflake. I need to set parameters to query the parameterized views.
Can you please help to set snowflake session variable through powerbi before running select query on view.

```
Set dat_parameter='2022-01-01'
Select * from parameterized_view
```

Power bi is not accepting set statement

Comment: does it show any errors?

Comment: I am getting this error - "DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [0A000] Actual statement count 2 did not match the desired statement count 1." How can i set multi_statement_count : 2 from power bi? When i try to run only set statement It gives this error = "Native queries aren't supported by this value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting enablefolding=false as shown below in power bi and setting multi+statement_count = 0 in snowflake. I am able to extract the data from parameterized view in snowflake.

power bi:

```
= Value.NativeQuery(Snowflake.Databases("XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com","compute_wh"){[Name="TESTDB"]}[Data], 
"set abc=60001;select * from testdb.public.param_view", null, [EnableFolding=false])
```

Snowflake:

```
alter account set MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT = 0;
```

parameterized view creation:

```
create or replace view param_view AS
select * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER where C_CUSTKEY = $abc;
```